# Is there any way to preview the URL of a t.co link on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, url-shortening

They've basically taken over the URL shortening game, but without offering the features the other shorteners do. For instance, http://is.gd allows you to set a setting which will show you the link you're being sent to, allowing you to click through after you've checked it out.

t.co seems to require me to blindly follow links, even though they've obscured what the link is.

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/178/how-can-i-be-certain-that-a-url-shortened-link-i-click-isnt-going-to-send-me-to

Comment: I wrote a Google Mobilizer bookmarklet that lets links on your Twitter timeline be opened with Google Mobilizer - http://mvark.blogspot.in/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html This lets you see minimalist, text-only content related to those pages without the fear of contracting malware from dubious links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Rex Swain's HTTP Viewer](http://rexswain.com/httpview) isn't specifically for unshortening URLs, but is a general purpose tool to view what an HTTP request returns. It can be used to examine what a shortened URL will redirect to.
- [Unfurlr](http://unfurlr.com/) is an experimental service from MailChimp for untangling shortened URLs.
- [Where Does This Link Go](http://wheredoesthislinkgo.com/) is specially​ purposed for this, but doesn't provide as much information. It does, however, offer [its code on GitHub](https://github.com/robertgreiner/WhereDoesThisLinkGo).  *(h/t [Dragomok](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/124176/dragomok))*

Answer (score 0):

You can use Curl to peek at redirected URLs:

```
curl -I https://t.co/0BACDYaBmU
```

`-I` sends a HEAD request.  Do not use `-L` / `--location` which will reveal that you followed the link (spammers could use it to get an IP address or confirm that an email address is in use).