# How can I find out what a goo.gl URL leads to, without visiting it?

Tags: links, url-shortening, goo.gl

[goo.gl](http://goo.gl) allows us to shorten URLs. For example, http://goo.gl/Y5VIoG will link to http://google.com

How can we determine what URL the goo.gl link points to without actually visiting it?

For example, how can we see that the link http://goo.gl/Y5VIoG points to http://google.com without actually clicking on it?

Is there an official way to do this (provided by Google instead of a 3rd party)?

Comment: There are a few browser extensions which purport to be able to "lengthen" shortened URLs from a number of different services.

Comment: http://longurl.org/ also supports a ton of shorteners, including goo.gl.

Comment: See also: [How can I be certain that a URL-shortened link I click isn't going to send me to a dangerous or unwanted site?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/178)

Comment: See also: [Is there any way to preview the URL of a t.co link on Twitter?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20106/is-there-any-way-to-preview-the-url-of-a-t-co-link-on-twitter/)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Adding a `.info` after the URL will give you detailed analytics of the short URL, including:

- **The full URL being pointed to**
- QR Code
- Number of clicks over various timeframes
- Visitor information:

  - Referrers
  - Browsers
  - Platforms (Windows, et al.)
  - Country of origin

For instance: [This question](http://goo.gl/e1kTPw): http://goo.gl/e1kTPw.info

For a better example, here's the example link from [Goo.gl Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/190768): http://goo.gl/l6MS.info

(Note: Analytics for all goo.gl short URLs are publicly visible to all users.)

Comment: If you use `http://goo.gl/XXXXXXX.qr` you'll get a QR code back for the goo.gl URL. Can be handy.

Comment: Wow, 66.7% of the people are from this answer

Comment: You can also now append a `+` to the end of a url http://goo.gl/e1kTPw+ which gives the same result as `.info` (and incidentally is the same character used to preview bit.ly links)

Comment: Google has created 'Firebase Dynamic Links' which take the form `https://abc123.app.goo.gl/WXYZ` and do not support `+` or `.info`. According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug) you can add `?d=1` to the end of the URL to determine where it goes: `https://abc123.app.goo.gl/WXYZ?d=1`

Comment: wow, using `?d=1` GET args is a HUGE downgrade ... with appending `.info`, a simple fat-finger will just get you an error from google.  With GET args, fat-fingering it takes you to the page!  So much for being 120% sure you don't actually visit the (possibly malicious) page!

Answer (score 0):

take a look here
https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/

and example of the API running is here:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/urlshortener/v1/urlshortener.url.get?shortUrl=http%253A%252F%252Fgoo.gl%252FY5VIoG&_h=1&

which returns:

{
 "kind": "urlshortener#url",
 "id": "http://goo.gl/Y5VIoG",
 "longUrl": "http://google.com/",
 "status": "OK"
}